# do not the overwrite with BufferedWritter

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I created an object of a class in java and wrote information of this object in a file with `BufferedWriter`.

But when I create a new object and write information of this in the file, I lose the previous information of previous object.

How can I write in the file with `BufferedWriter` without overwriting a file?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) class it allows you to specify if you want to overwrite or append to the file in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Java default is overwriting the file. You can specify that you wish to append to a file.

```
boolean append=true;
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("yourfile.txt"),append);
BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(writer);

// do your writing stuff
```

Comment: There is no boolean parameter in File constructor.

Comment: @Nfear, my appologies, the boolean parameter was meant for the FileWriters constructor. I edited the code. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to append to a file that already exists, you can use the following:

```
BufferedWriter bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("file.txt"), true));
```